# i can't insert more than 2 from with check box with ajax

Tags: mysql, ajax

i wanna insert to according to the number of check boxes

if i check one checkbox than insert one form, if check two checkbox insert two form

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fg3hG.png)

and here is my script

```
$('#insertRegularCheck').click(function(){
          var kindOfValue = ['낙상위험','욕창위험측정','인지기능검사','욕구사정'];
          var elderName = $('input[name=elderName]').val();
          var elderId = $('input[name=elderId]').val();
          for(var i=0;i<kindOfValue.length;i++){
              formData = $('#regularCheck').serializeArray();
              var elderRegularCheckDoingDate = $('#elderRegularCheckDoingDate')
              var elderRegularCheckPlanDate = $('#elderRegularCheckPlanDate')
              var $chk = $('#elderRegularCheckCategory'+i+''); 
              if($chk.is(':checked')){
                  formData.push({
                      name : "elderName", 
                      value : elderName
                  });
                  formData.push({
                      name : "elderId", 
                      value : elderId
                  });
                  formData.push({
                      name : $chk.attr('name'), 
                      value : kindOfValue[i]
                  }); 
                  formData.push({
                      name : "elderRegularCheckPlanDate",
                      value : elderRegularCheckPlanDate.val()
                  })
                  formData.push({
                      name : "elderRegularCheckDoingDate",
                      value : elderRegularCheckDoingDate.val()
                  });
                  console.log(formData);
                  $.ajax({
                      type  :   'POST',
                      url   :   '/employee/insertRegularCheck',
                      data  :   formData,
                      traditional :true,
                      success   :   function(data){
                          console.log('success')
                      },
                      error :   function(error){
                          console.log("error", error)
                      }
                  })
              }
          }
      })
```

and here is my form

```
<h3>검사 등록 및 수정</h3>
                <div class="row" >
                    <div class="col-sm-12" >
                        <form id="regularCheck">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <h4>검사 선택</h4>
                                <label style="margin-right:10px;"><input name="elderRegularCheckCategory" id="elderRegularCheckCategory0" type="checkbox" value="낙상위험">낙상위험측정</label>
                                <label style="margin-right:10px;"><input name="elderRegularCheckCategory" id="elderRegularCheckCategory1" type="checkbox" value="욕창위험측정">욕창위험측정</label>
                                <label style="margin-right:10px;"><input name="elderRegularCheckCategory" id="elderRegularCheckCategory2" type="checkbox" value="인지기능검사">인지기능검사</label>
                                <label style="margin-right:10px;"><input name="elderRegularCheckCategory" id="elderRegularCheckCategory3" type="checkbox" value="욕구사정">욕구사정</label></br>
                                <h4>날짜 선택</h4>
                                <label>계획 날짜<input name="elderRegularCheckPlanDate" id="elderRegularCheckPlanDate" class="date"></label>
                                <label>시행 날짜<input name="elderRegularCheckDoingDate" id="elderRegularCheckDoingDate" class="date"></label>
                                <button id="insertRegularCheck" type="button" class="btn btn-metis-5 btn-xs" style="text-align: right; margin-left: 10px;">등록하기/수정하기</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
```

i'm curious it's sometimes work sometimes makes

```
Duplicate entry 'check_57' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

this error

Comment: this feels like an SQL error,

Comment: Looks like an SQL error. You never send anything in your ajax anyways.